# Import only used range from workbook

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I am trying to browse a file and get the sheet name to import data in my existing file.

My code works well when I give the fixed range for the file to be imported.(highlighted)
I want to get the used range of the file to imported and extract the exact date.

Please see my code below

```
Sub BrowseSourceData()
    Dim wsht_Temp As Workbook
    Dim varFile As Variant
    Dim fileLoc As String
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim fileExtn As Long
    Dim mydata As String
    Dim shtName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Source Data")

    ws.Activate
    ws.Cells.Clear

    fileLoc = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xls*;,*.xls*," & " Comma Seperated Files (*.csv),*.csv,", , "Select a file", , False)

    If fileLoc = "False" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        '---Get the filename and file loaction
        'fileExtn = InStr(fileLoc, "csv")
        fileName = Mid$(fileLoc, 1 + InStrRev(fileLoc, "\"), Len(fileLoc))
        filePath = Mid$(fileLoc, 1, InStrRev(fileLoc, "\"))


        'If fileExtn > 0 Then
         If InStr(fileLoc, "csv") Or InStr(fileLoc, "CSV") > 0 Then
           Call loadDataFromCSV(fileLoc)
       Else
        'dynamic sheet naming
        Set wsht_Temp = Workbooks.Open(filePath & "\" & fileName, False)
        wsht_Temp.Close False
         mydata = "='" & filePath & "[" & fileName & "]" & shtName & ***"'!$A$1:$AC$10000"***
        ***With ws.Range("A1:L10000")***
        .Formula = mydata
        'convert formula to text
        .Value = .Value
        End With
        End If
    End If
    Set wsht_Temp = Nothing

    Sheets("HomePage").Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you accurately define the source range, you can apply the **external:=true** parameter to the .Address property. You only need a relative address to the cell in the top-left corner.

```
Set wsht_Temp = Workbooks.Open(filePath & "\" & fileName, False)
mydata = "='" & wsht_Temp.worksheets(shtName).range("A1").address(0, 0, external:=true)
wsht_Temp.Close False
```

Try an Intersect of columns A:L and the worksheet's .UsedRange property.

```
With intersect(ws.Range("A:L"), ws.usedrange)
    .formula = myData
    .value = .value
end with
```

Comment: Hi Jeeped, Thank you for your reply. The line mydata = "='" & wsht_Temp.worksheets(shtName).range("A1").address(0, 0, external:=true) gives error as 'shtName is blank at this point

Comment: Then you should probably assign a worksheet name to it.